# jq - if a name is in a disctionary list exists, return a row of values

Tags: jq

Given the following input

```
{
  "environment": [
    {
      "name": "AAA",
      "value": "1111"
    },
    {
      "name": "BBB",
      "value": "2222"
    },
    {
      "name": "CCC",
      "value": "3333"
    },
    {
      "name": "DDD",
      "value": "4444"
    }
  ]
}
```

If CCC exists, then write out on a single line of certain values
1111, 2222, 4444
Else
Write Nothing

jq -r '.environment[] | select (.name == "CCC") | [.name, .value] | @csv'

Don't know how to write the other values.

Would like to see the values
1111, 2222, 3333

Comment: I don't quite understand what you are trying to achieve but maybe running this can help you find the way to get there: `jq -r '.environment[] | if .name == "CCC" then "found" else "read" end + ": \(.value)"'` outputs `read: 1111` `read: 2222` `found: 3333` `read: 4444` on separate lines. [Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/dy5D7sMj_j0)

Comment: TomC: Please fix the JSON and the statement of the problem. You refer to "CCC" and "CCCC", and there are two statements about the expected output.  Also, you mention @csv, but the sample outputs seem to use ", " as the separator.

Comment: You have to be careful with your text editor: you have a mix of "normal" double quotes and "curly" quotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sample is not quite valid JSON, but after fixing it, the following will produce the output you first mention (without the "3333"), in accordance with my best guess as to your requirements:

```
jq -r '.environment
   | (map(.name) | index("CCC")) as $ix
   | select($ix)
   | del(.[$ix])
   | map(.value)
   | join(", ")
'
```

For very large arrays, you would probably want to tweak this a bit to avoid mapping the entire array.

Answer (score 1):

```bash
jq -r --arg wanted "CCC" '
    .environment
    | if any(.name == $wanted)
        then map(.value) | @csv
        else empty
      end
' << END_INPUT
  {
    "environment": [
      {
        "name": "AAA",
        "value": "1111"
      },
      {
        "name": "BBB",
        "value": "2222"
      },
      {
        "name": "CCC",
        "value": "3333"
      },
      {
        "name": "DDD",
        "value": "4444"
      }
    ]
  }
END_INPUT
```

```
"1111","2222","3333","4444"
```